# How to pass complex type object to custom attribute in Blazor Server?

Tags: object, parameters, attributes, blazor, custom-attributes

I have custom attribute called TestAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class TestAttribute: Attribute
{
    IList<ComplexType> Template;
    public TestAttribute(IList<ComplexType> _template)
    {
       Template = _template;
    }
}
```

In my `test.razor` file I'm including that attribute.

```
@attribute [TestAttribute(myParam)]
```

`myParam` is defined in `test.razor.cs` file.

```
public IList<ComplexType> myParam = new List<ComplexType>(){
  new ComplexType {Name = "1", type="A"},
  new ComplexType {Name = "2", type="B"},
  new ComplexType {Name = "3", type="A"},
};
```

But it gives the error object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property. Error pops from here -> `@attribute [TestAttribute(myParam)]`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Attributes are compiletime values. Use the attribute to target the property not the class that has the value. Then use reflection to get the value.

Comment: @BrianParker Could you please explain it little bit more?

Comment: As Brian has stated attributes are assigned at compile time, not run time.  You set them in your code, not from a property or field in a class instance. So to answer your question: You can't.  What are you actually trying to do with your attribute?  I've a feeling you may need an interface, but with no knowledge of the usage, I'm guessing.

Comment: Attributes can only take primitive types as parameters this is a CLR restriction. One of the things you can do is take a `string` as a parameter and use `nameof(SomeProperty)` as the parameter. Then the attribute holds the name of the property that holds the `List<...>`.  You can then use reflection to extract the values. As Shaun pointed out this maybe a better case for an interface. I use attributes like this in SDK's that consume models if the model is internal an interface maybe better.